# Resize and make sizes equal 0 GridLayout (android)

Tags: android, grid-layout

In my application I have several buttons with images in its drawableTop property. Also, every Button has a label (text).

All images have the same size: 394px X 336px.

I want all the buttons to have the same size when using GridLayout. Also, I don't want the user to scroll down to see the rest of the buttons. I want all the buttons to be placed in just one screen.

I'm trying to do this in here, but since images are big (I am using the cellphone emulator), user needs to scroll down to see the rest of the buttons and also, even though all images have the same size, buttons don't have the same size.

Here is my code (buttons names and images don't matter, I just wanted to create a 2X2 grid with same size for all items, no scrolling at all):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2" >
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/this_is_a_test" 
            android:background="@layout/roundcorners"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:text="This is a test"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/test">
        </Button>    

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/this_is_a_test" 
            android:background="@layout/roundcorners"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:text="This is a test"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/test">
        </Button>    

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/this_is_a_test" 
            android:background="@layout/roundcorners"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:text="This is a test"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/test">
        </Button>    

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/this_is_a_test" 
            android:background="@layout/roundcorners"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:text="This is a test"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/test">
        </Button>    


</GridLayout>
```

Can you guys help me, please?

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem yet? Im a newbie of Android,and have the similar issue, in my code I did this `params.setGravity(Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);`, it gave me the same size buttons, but all buttons cannot fill out the screen, any help?